# Different than expected items in MemoryCache

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, caching

When starting my application, I'm loading many configuration parameters into the MemoryCache and I can confirm that after doing that (in the Startup.cs), that there are about 280 entries inside of the cache.

When I inject a IMemoryCache into a controller and return all the entries as json, there are suddenly only 16 items inside and they are none of the ones that I loaded initially.

What could be reasons that this is happening? I was looking for places where the cache could be cleared but didn't find any.
Is the IMemoryCache not implemented as a singleton?

In the Startup.ConfigureServices I'm adding the memory cache as one of the first statements:

```
services.AddMemoryCache();
```

I'm loading the items initially like this:

```
var spp = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<ISysParamProvider<IDbContext>>();
spp.LoadAll();
```

Could the problem be, that a new ServiceProvider is built here?
If so, how can I get the ISysParamProvider instance instead?

Do I have to consider anything else so that I will get this instance injected into the controller?

Thanks in advance

The LoadAll()-method looks like this:

```
public async Task LoadAll()
    {
        var sysParams= this.db.Set<SysParam>().ToList();

        foreach (var sysParam in sysParams)
        {
            if (!this.cache.TryGetValue(sysParam.ParamName, out _))
            {
                var cacheentryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                    .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));

                this.cache.Set(sysParam.ParamName, sysParam.ParamValue, cacheentryOptions);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How exactly are you populating the cache? Are you setting the `SizeLimit` against the MemoryCache?

Comment: @PeterCsala I've added the LoadAll() that populates the cache. I'm not setting a SizeLimit

Comment: Is `this.cache` initialized via DI?

Comment: yes exactly, I inject an IMemoryCache into the constructor

Comment: Then most probably you are having two separate MemoryCache instances due to the `services.BuildServiceProvider()`.

Comment: That's what I'm expecting as well. Is there a way to get an instance of the sysparamprovider without the BuildServiceProvider?

Comment: A dirty solution could be to overwrite the [`CreateServiceProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.startupbase.createserviceprovider?view=aspnetcore-6.0) method as well in your startup. 1) Build the provider there 2) Call the cache population logic 3) Return with the provider

Comment: Did the proposed solution work for you?

Comment: no unfortunately not, but what did work is injecting the ISysParamProvider into the Configure method and populate the cache there

Comment: Please post an answer and mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed with the `services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<ISysParamProvider<IDbContext>>();` as it seemed to have created another instance of the IMemoryCache (which is injected in the ISysParamProvider).

The solution to this was to inject the `ISysParamProvider` into the `Configure` method of the Startup and fill the cache there via `spp.LoadAll()`. By doing that, the correct `IMemoryCache` was injected into `ISysParamProvider`.